# curl url to get the json file for issues in my repository

Tags: git, curl

I just have started off to use github api to pull issues records from our repository. 
When I hit,

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://2b9e36bvb9e36b82d38b9c0ab2b9e36b82d3:x-oauth-basic@rnd.git.corp/newlands/hello-world/issues
```

I get the following output.

```
> <html><body>You are being <a
> href="https://rnd.git.corp/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Frnd.git.corp%2Fnewlands%2Fhello-world%2Fissues">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Is there anything wrong with my curl command ? it ideally should print the issue list in my repository as per git api doc. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If `rnd.git.corp` is the according URL to `api.github.com`, you maybe just miss the `/repos`, like `https://rnd.git.corp/repos/newlands/hello-world/issues`

Comment: `https://rnd.git.corp/newlands/hello-world` this is my respositry URL, different from api.github.com.

Comment: That's exactly what I said and the problem probably is. `https://github.com/Vampire/teamcity-sourceforge/issues` is one of my repositories issues as web page, `https://api.github.com/Vampire/teamcity-sourceforge/issues` is an invalid URL and `https://api.github.com/repos/Vampire/teamcity-sourceforge/issues` is the API URL to get the issues as JSON string. Probably similar for GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: missed to tell you that I tried with /repos added in the url, i.e., `https://rnd.git.corp/repos/newlands/hello-world/issues`. It's still the same. anything else I'm missing ?

Comment: Well, then you maybe do the authentication wrongly, as you are redirected to a login page? Did you try to open the link in a web browser where you are logged in already?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vampire. I think I got solution. We've got [enterprise github](https://enterprise.github.com/home) install in our Org, whose api access URL is slightly [different](https://developer.github.com/v3/enterprise/#endpoint-urls).

So, for GitHub Enterprise the URL should be something like,

```
https://rnd.git.corp/api/v3/newlands/hello-world/issues
```

If someone wants to add more or correct this answer, feel free. Peace!